# Feedback Filtered-x LMS algorithm: question about theory

Tags: adaptive-algorithms, lms, noise-cancellation, feedback

I was reading some of papers about the Active Noise Cancellation; in particular about the Filtered-x LMS algorithm, also known as FxLMS.

It seems that classic FxLMS (also called **Feedforward FxLMS**) algorithm is suitable to cancel **broadband noise** (white noise), while its Feedback version (the **Feedback FxLMS**, also abbreviated to FB-FxLMS) is suitable to cancel a **narrowband noise** (like sinusoid + white noise), but not a broadband noise.

I read that this is due to the fact that the Feedforward FxLMS has the primary noise provided as reference signal, while the FB-FxLMS has not the reference signal initially available, but it needs to estimate it (using the error signal).
And this estimation process is possible only if the primary noise has a predictable nature, so it can't be a white noise.

Is there someone (maybe who has already worked with the Feedback FxLMS algorithm) who can confirm this property of the Feedback FxLMS?

**PS:** As requested in the comments, here are the block diagrams of the two algorithms:

- **FxLMS block diagram:**

[image: FxLMS block diagram]

- **Feedback FxLMS block diagram**

[image: Feedback FxLMS algorithm]

Comment: what's the "*FX*" stand for?

Comment: "Fx" stands for "Filtered-x". I'll change the title for clarity.
The Filtered-x LMS (FxLMS) algorithm distinguishes from LMS, because weights (in the update equation) are updated not using input x[n] (as it happens in LMS), but using a filtered version of x[n], precisely x[n] filtered by S^(z).
S^(z) is an estimate of the secondary path S(z).
S(z) represents the transfer function of the channel from the loudspeaker (which is situated at the output of the adaptive filter W(z)) to the error microphone.

Comment: so then the LMS converges to an inverse to the filter of $x[n]$.  does the unfiltered $x[n]$ (or a delayed version) become the *"desired signal"*, what we used to call "$d[n]$"?

Comment: I'm not sure if I well understood your questions; I'll try to answer them.
The adaptive filter $W(z)$ in LMS tends to be as close as possible to the primary path $P(z)$, while the adaptive filter in FxLMS aims to make the output of $S(z)$ equal to $d[n]$ (these signals are added up at the sum-node).
E.g: In FxLMS, if $P(z)$ consists in a Dirac delta delayed of 128 samples, and $S(z)$ consists in a delta delayed of 65 samples, then $W(z)$ converges to a delta delayed of 62 samples.
In both LMS and FxLMS, the desired response $d[n]$ is the result of $x[n]$ filtered by the primary path $P(z)$.

Comment: a block diagram would be the easiest for me to comprehend.

Comment: I've added two links, at the bottom of the original post, where you can find the two block diagrams.

Comment: if you hit "**edit**" and look under "**Body**", you will see some editing tools, one of which is the picture insert tool.  i used that along with links to the block diagrams from the links you included.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the links and I've added the two right pictures. Thanks for the advice ;)